# Login Facebook SDK C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

after download and install facebook c# sdk, I cant find function WebFacebook.Navigate..

why this happen to me? cz this I cannot continue my project. any idea?
Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Facebook;

namespace FaceBook
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string OAuthURL = @" https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1615871262024203&redirect_uri= https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token ";

            WebFacebook.Navigate(OAuthURL);                 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Guessing you're (sort of) following the code here (or similar): http://www.emoticode.net/c-sharp/facebook-oauth-getting-basic-user-infos.html

But you apparently skipped the step where you need to put a `WebBrowser` control on your form/window and name it `webfacebook` which would allow that `Navigate` call to actually mean something...